# How to get request headers in instagram.com

Tags: selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver, instagram, request-headers

I'm working on a small-scale instagram scraping project mainly using selenium and the python requests module. I discovered that when the Request Header changes for [www.instagram.com](http://www.instagram.com), the text that I get from using
`requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/<address>/?__a=1")`
Returns the HTML code for the webpage. Instead I was expecting it to be the json text containing post details. Currently, it works fine if I change the headers manually. 
How do I automatically get the request header using selenium or requests? I'm expecting to get the text labeled in the image attached:
[www.instagram.com Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izpgz.jpg)
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/<address>/?__a=1")
print(response.status_code)
print(response.headers)
print(response.json())
```

As I see in the headers printed out on to console, there is a `set-cookie` header. If this is something that you are looking for, then you may use this line to extract only this header:

```
print(resp.headers['Set-Cookie'])
```